# Make the content of a table overlay the table border

Tags: html, css

Is there a trick to make the backgoud color of the thead overlay the border of the table? The solution only needs to work in chrome (node-webkit). Added a fiddle and image to illustrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/bc5GZ/4/embedded/result/
http://postimg.org/image/cjoulhs5f/

```
 table{
   border:black 1px solid;
 }

 thead{
   /*some clever code to make the background of thead overlay the table border*/
 }
```

**Edit:** Edited the fiddle to make the code easier to read and added a picture to illustrate

Comment: do you want table border 1 color and thead border another?

Comment: No.. I want the background color of the thead to overlay the color of the table border. Make the thead expand 1px left, right and up, so the table border don't show around the thead. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really clear on what your looking for but try negative margins or relative positioning.

Comment: I tried but I can't find a solution... Added the jsfiddle to illustrate, if you look at the border of the thead you probably understand what i mean (i hope)

Answer (score 0):

Do you looking for this..

**EDIT**

fiddle-1:  http://jsfiddle.net/WTc3J/3/

```
No border for thead
```

fiddle-2: http://jsfiddle.net/WTc3J/4/

```
No border for td , thead, and table
```

Hope this will help you..let me know..

Comment: Thanks, but no.. Im looking for a way to remove all the borders including the table border around thead... but still have "table {border:1px solid black;}"

Comment: I have just update my fiddle, so it's much cleaner, and hopefully easier to spot my problem :)

Comment: that is you need no border for table and thead , ok?\

Comment: @user3320468, no border for td, th and table..sure?

Comment: No, no border around thead. If you the border from the table the edge looks awkward, but the thead is red and dark gray and doesn't look good with a light gray border

Comment: @user3320468, please check my updated answer. and look the first fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `div` elements with their respective `display` properties instead of tables, table cells and rows; and style them accordingly (tables are somewhat deprecated now - plus divs are easier to render and they're friendlier with css. Divs are the future, yay!).

```
<div class=table>
    <div class=table_header>
        <div class=header_cell>A</div>
        <div class=header_cell>B</div>
        <div class=header_cell>C</div>
    </div>
    <div class=table_row>
            <div class=table_cell>1</div>
            <div class=table_cell>2</div>
            <div class=table_cell>3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WTc3J/2/).

Comment: Sorry, but i don't believe you. Im displaying tabular data, the things tables was intended to do. A solution with divs is messy and hackis, and probably requires a bunch more css and the HTML becomes messy. (but I could be wrong..)

Comment: While it may be true that tables were designed to be… tables, let's note that they were implemented a long time ago. Divs and CSS are **now** what's better for layout. As I said, they have performance enhancements to render lots of elements and things like that, not to mention they have better support for CSS. In fact I once read that HTML actually uses divs to render tables. But anyway, that's why I said "you can…" and not "you must…".